# Multiple models or a single model with multiple custom data types?

Tags: mvc, model

I am writting a small webapp for learning.

Is it better / best practice to create multiple models or one model with multiple custom data types? For example:

Let's say the web app is "PublicLibrary." The library would have shelves. Shelves would have books and locations. Books would have titles, authors, text and a dewey decimal number.

Would it be better to have a Book model, a shelf model (couldn't come up with a better example for this), and a Library model; or a book class, a shelf class, and a Library model that holds those classes. I understand that a model *is* a class, but hopefully my question makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create *classes* for every object type that does not have a built-in type.

For example, a `Library` would contain `Books`, but a `Book` would likely use a built-in string type for the dewey decimal number (use a string because you are not performing math on it) and title. Author could be a string, but would likely be reused on multiple books and may have further properties so should stand alone as its own object.

We can provide better guidance if you could post a diagram showing your design along with specific questions regarding how to achieve your goal with the design.

Comment: I think that pretty much answers, and it was what I thought... My only other additional question would be if this library could contain eBooks and the text was now "movie_file." Would you make a Model for 'media' or just book, or book AND ebook?

Comment: I would have separate entities for media types, but a common interface. Their _identity_ is different: one is a book, one is audio. But they can both be `checked out` or `returned`, for example.